# Is DefaultThreadFactory itself thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

The Java Executor framework offers the [DefaultThreadFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory%28%29) for creating threads.

Is `DefaultThreadFactory` itself safe for concurrent use by multiple threads? Or must I take care to have only one `DefaultThreadFactory` per thread?

I know it is generally best practice to start new threads only from one "main" thread, but let's assume a pre-existing code base.

It would be great if the answer included a short explanation of *why* you are sure that `DefaultThreadFactory` is thread-safe or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sotirios' answer is correct but I'd like to add some more specifics.

> Is DefaultThreadFactory itself safe for concurrent use by multiple threads?

Yes.  As Sotirios mentions, the only shared state is the thread-number which is handled with an `AtomicInteger`.

> Or must I take care to have only one DefaultThreadFactory per thread?

This is a bit contradictory.  Each `DefaultThreadFactory` is used by all threads created by a thread-pool.  You can't have a thread-factory per thread but you *can* share thread-factories between pools if you'd like.  The only reason why a new instance of the `DefaultThreadFactory` is created for each pool is, I suspect, just to get a new thread-name counter for each pool.

> I know it is generally best practice to start new threads only from one "main" thread...

This is not a common practice on any significantly complex multithreaded application.  I fork threads or thread-pools from a large number of different classes.  I'd rather have each class be responsible for its own background tasks then manage them in some central location.

> why you are sure that DefaultThreadFactory is thread-safe or not.

See the code that Sotirios posted.  If your question *really* is whether or not you have to write a thread-safe factory then it is enough to show how the `java.util.concurrent` classes use it.  Here a small code sample from `ThreadPoolExecutor` which backs the `Executors` thread pools.

```
private Thread addThread(Runnable firstTask) {
    Worker w = new Worker(firstTask);
    Thread t = threadFactory.newThread(w);
    ...
```

Notice that there is no locking around the use of factory.  If you use the same factory in different thread-pools then multiple threads can certainly be executing it at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the `ThreadPoolExecutor` example. If Doug Lea treats `DefaultThreadFactory` as thread-safe, so can I. :-)

Comment: Unrelated: What kind of projects do you work on that use so much self managed concurrency (_I fork threads or thread-pools from a large number of different classes_)? You know your subject very well.

Comment: You know the subject well too @SotiriosDelimanolis.  I just write a lot of 24/365 POJO applications.  Never done J2EE so if I want threads I have to write them.  We do let Jetty manage its own :-).  We use jgroups network stack for all of our communications as well which fork a ton o' threads.  What I'd love to know more about is Peter's fu.  Love to know about the concurrency challenges in his high performance trading systems.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle JDK7 implementation of `DefaultThreadFactory#newThread(Runnable)` is

```
public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    Thread t = new Thread(group, r,
                          namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                          0);
    if (t.isDaemon())
        t.setDaemon(false);
    if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
        t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    return t;
}
```

where `threadNumber` is an `AtomicInteger`. Nothing other objects are shared or mutable so this implementation is thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the documentation which states one way or the other, but if you look at the code for OpenJDK, it is thread safe as the only mutable shared state is two AtomicInteger(s)